# How expensive is a blocked mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

Say I have a mutex and thread 1 locked the mutex. Now, thread 2 tries to acquire the lock but it is blocked, say for a couple of seconds. How expensive is this blocked thread? Can the executing hardware thread be rescheduled to do something computationally more expensive? If yes, then who checks if the mutex gets unlocked?

**EDIT**: Ok so I try to reformulate what I wanted to ask.

What I dont really understand is how the following works. thread 2 got blocked, so what exactly does thread 2 do? From the answer it seems like it is not just constantly checking if the mutex gets unlocked. If this were the case, I would consider a blocked thread expensive, as I am using one of my hardware threads just for checking if some boolean value changes.

So am I correct in thinking that when the mutex gets released by thread 1, thread 1 notifies the sheduler and the shedular assigns a hardware thread to execute thread 2 which is waiting?

Comment: please provide some example code, as is your question is a bit too abstract. On the other hand, once you have example code you could measure yourself :P

Comment: When a thread blocks, the OS assigns another thread to run. That's the point of having multiple threads. And the OS keeps a list of threads that are blocked on a mutex, and when the thread that locked the mutex unlocks it the OS picks one of the blocked threads to get the lock and resume execution.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, I was thinking in a very wrong way about a thread blocking. So if a lock goes out of scope, there is some code in the destructor that tells the OS that the  locked mutex is now unlocked?

Comment: If a `std::mutex` goes out of scope while locked, that is undefined behavior. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex 

Even with non-std implementations, it's a reasonable expectation for you to unlock before going out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

I am reading your questions as:

> How expensive is a locked mutex?

Mutex can be considered as an integer in memory.
A thread trying to lock on a mutex has to read the existing state of the mutex and can set it depending on the value read.

```
test_and_set( &mutex_value, 0, 1 );   // if mutex_value is 0, set to 1
```

The trick is that both the read and write (also called test-and-set) operation should be atomic. The atomicity is achieved with CPU support.

However, the test-and-set operation doesn't offer any mechanism to block/wait.
CPU has no knowledge of threads blocking on a mutex. The OS takes the responsibility to manage the blocking by providing system calls to users. The implementation varies from OS to OS. In case of Linux, you can consider futex or pthreads as an example.

The overall costs of using a mutex sums up to the test-and-set operation and the system calls used to implement the mutex.
The test-and set operation is almost constant and is insignificant compared to the cost the other operation can amount to.

If there a multiple threads trying to acquire the lock, the cost of
    mutex can be accredited to the following:

```
    1. Kernel scheduling overhead cost
    2. Context switch overhead cost
```

**Kernel scheduling overhead**

What happens to other threads, if one thread has already acquired lock on a mutex?

The other threads will continue. If any other thread(s) attempting to lock a mutex that is already locked, OS will (re)schedule the other thread(s) to wait. As soon as the original thread unlocks the mutex, kernel will wake up one of the threads waiting on the mutex.

**Context switch overhead**

User space code should be designed in such a manner that a thread should spend a very less time trying to lock on a mutex. If you have multiple thread trying to acquire lock on a mutex at multiple places, it may result in a disaster and the performance may be as poor as a single thread serving all requests.

> Can the executing hardware thread be resheduled to do something
>   computationally more expensive?

If I am getting your question correctly, the thread which has acquired the lock can be context switched, depending on the scheduling mechanism. But, that is an overhead of multi-threaded programming, itself. 
Can you provide a use case, to define this problem clearly?

> who checks if the mutex gets unlocked?

Definitely the OS scheduler. Note, it is not just a blind sleep().

Answer (score 1):

Threads are just a logical OS concept. There are no "hardware threads". Hardware has cores. The OS schedules a core to run a thread for a certain amount of time. If a thread gets blocked, there are always plenty left to run.

Taking your example, with mutexes, if thread 2 is blocked, the OS takes it off schedule and puts it in a queue associated with the mutex. When thread 1 releases the lock, it notifies the scheduler, which takes thread 2 off the queue and puts it back on the schedule. A blocked thread isn't using compute resources. However, there **is** overhead involved in the actual lock/unlock operation, which is an OS scheduling call.

That overhead is not insignificant, so you would generally use mutexes if you have longer tasks (reasonably longer than a scheduling time slice) and not too much lock competition.

> So if a lock goes out of scope, there is some code in the destructor that tells the OS that the locked mutex is now unlocked? 
>   Blockquote

If a `std::mutex` goes out of scope while locked, that is undefined behavior. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex) Even with non-std mutex implementations, it's reasonable to expect one to unlock before going out of scope.

Keep in mind that there are other kinds of "lock" (like spinlock...which itself has many versions) but we're only talking about mutexes here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont see where I wrote that the mutex went out of scope while beeing locked. I just wrote: So if a lock goes out of scope, there is some code in the destructor that tells the OS that the locked mutex is now unlocked?

Comment: Hmm. Did I fully answer your question? Undefined behavior basically means that the library implementation can do whatever it wants. It could leave it locked (probably eventually leading to a deadlock). It could be nice enough to tell the OS to unlock it for you, but honestly I would rather it not. IMHO it's a programming error to destroy a locked mutex. I would rather run into the deadlock (which is relatively easy to debug) than a subtle race condition. MSVC's std::mutex throws an assertion in debug mode but doesn't in release (not sure what it does in that case).

Comment: If you *want* an automatic mechanism for locking/unlocking a mutex based on object lifetime, you can use `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock`. These wrap a mutex (passed into the constructor) and they automatically unlock the mutex when the lock_guard or unique_lock object goes out of scope. (note: the mutex doesn't go out of scope, just the wrapper instance) This is the way you should do it because it's more exception safe and less error prone.

Comment: I am not sure why you are telling me this. As I said, I never said anything about letting a locked mutex go out of scope...

Comment: BTW, are you sure there is no such thing as a hardware thread? My computer has 4 cores, but it has 8 hardware threads, so the OS is able to run 8 threads in parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about it.

I can't say whether or not there might be some obscure system that has some kind of hardware concept of threads. But if we're talking about an everyday system with an everyday CPU and an everyday OS, today the hardware doesn't have a meaningful concept of threads. You have to remember that a thread is basically just a stack. It can access the heap and instruction set of the process in belongs to. All a CPU cares about is the current instruction and where to find the next one. (Even though it *does* have a stack pointer to make things easier).

Comment: If you have an Intel chip, what you're probably seeing is Hyper-threading(tm). CPUs have many different circuits to do different kinds of operations. Most programs don't take full advantage of all the available circuits. Intel chips allow 2 threads to be run on 1 core at the same time to better utilize hardware concurrency. The operating system has to be hyperthreading aware/enabled in order to take advantage of this. If you have 4 cores, that's 2 x 4 = 8 threads that can run concurrently